# How to parse with Bash script? (platform MIPS)?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, json

```
$ curl -LNs "http://urladrescom/content.json" > content.json
```

**content.json**

```
{
   "k":[
      {
         "i":1,
         "n":"NAME 1",
         "p":[
            {
               "b":"Event 1",
               "c":"00:00",
               "d":"03:00"
            },
            {
               "b":"Event 2",
               "c":"23:00",
               "d":"00:00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "i":2,
         "n":"NAME 2",
         "p":[
            {
               "b":"Event 1",
               "c":"07:15",
               "d":"09:15"
            },
            {
               "b":"Event 2",
               "c":"22:00",
               "d":"23:15"
            },
            {
               "b":"Event 3",
               "c":"23:15",
               "d":"02:30"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "i":3,
         "n":"NAME 3",
         "p":[
            {
               "b":"Event 1",
               "c":"07:15",
               "d":"09:15"
            },
            {
               "b":"Event 2",
               "c":"22:00",
               "d":"23:15"
            },
            {
               "b":"Event 3",
               "c":"23:15",
               "d":"02:30"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to get the content in "NAME 2" under Event 1,2,3 with a Bash script (`grep`, `awk`, `sed`, etc..) (or Python in a Bash script cmd).

**I want print result :**

```
NAME 2 \ Event 1 \ 07:15 \ 09:15
NAME 2 \ Event 2 \ 22:00 \ 23:15
NAME 2 \ Event 3 \ 23:15 \ 02:30
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `jq` instead e.g. `jq -r --arg name "NAME 2" '.k[] | select(.n==$name) | .p[] | [$name, .b, .c, .d] | @tsv' content.json`

Comment: jq is not in my system. my system platform mips
only grep sed awk curl and cmd python !

Comment: @tioma You should be able to install `jq`, either by using your package manager, or by compiling it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Python to do what you want:

```
$ cat parse.py
#!/bin/python

import json
#from pprint import pprint

with open('content.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

for dict in data["k"]:
  if (dict["n"] == "NAME 2"):
    for elem in dict["p"]:
      print(dict["n"] + ' \\ ' + elem["b"] + ' \\ ' + elem["c"] + ' \\ ' + elem["d"])
```

#### Example

```
$ ./parse.py
NAME 2 \ Event 1 \ 07:15 \ 09:15
NAME 2 \ Event 2 \ 22:00 \ 23:15
NAME 2 \ Event 3 \ 23:15 \ 02:30
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the command line JSON parser [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)...

There might be a shorter `jq` expression that does this, but this is what I came up with:

```
$ jq -r --arg name "NAME 2" '.[][]|select(.n==$name).p[]|[$name,.[]]|join(" \\ ")' content.json
NAME 2 \ Event 1 \ 07:15 \ 09:15
NAME 2 \ Event 2 \ 22:00 \ 23:15
NAME 2 \ Event 3 \ 23:15 \ 02:30
```

Or, using slightly more selective code, [as suggested by steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463544/how-to-parse-with-bash-script-platform-mips/463572#comment843722_463544),

```
$ jq -r --arg name "NAME 2" '.k[]|select(.n==$name).p[]|[$name, .b, .c, .d]|join(" \\ ")' content.json
NAME 2 \ Event 1 \ 07:15 \ 09:15
NAME 2 \ Event 2 \ 22:00 \ 23:15
NAME 2 \ Event 3 \ 23:15 \ 02:30
```

`name` is a `jq` variable whose value is passed on the command line.  The `jq` code is doing five things:

1. Extract the `k` arrays in the data that we're interested in.
2. Select the particular array that we want to output (and the `p` bit from this).
3. Create an array for outputting (since the name is not part of the data, it has to be inserted).
4. Do output with the particular delimiter inserted.